# Finding out if a binary file has been compiled with stack smashing protection

Tags: c, linux, unix, command-line, binaryfiles

On a Linux, is there any way to tell if a binary file has been compiled with stack-smashing on/off from the command-line?

I am pretty sure that I have the protection on, but just for the sake of sanity, I'd like to write some tests for my binaries in case there ever comes a day when everything goes wrong and the protection is off... for some reason.

Comment: Can you disassemble it and look at some functions to see if they look like there's stack protection code in there?

Comment: If you go for the disassembly route, you should check for [stack-smashing protection prologues and epilogues](http://www.drdobbs.com/security/anatomy-of-a-stack-smashing-attack-and-h/240001832?pgno=2).

Comment: PS: The above link is broken, but you can find it on web.archive.org. e.g. [20180727](http://web.archive.org/web/20180727001715/https://www.drdobbs.com/security/anatomy-of-a-stack-smashing-attack-and-h/240001832?pgno=2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your your executable file format is **ELF**, and it *happens* to have been compiled by **GCC v4.3** or greater, which just *happened* to be passed the `-frecord-gcc-switches` command-line switch, then you could do the following:

```
$ gcc -frecord-gcc-switches -fno-stack-protector test.c
$ readelf -p .GCC.command.line a.out

String dump of section '.GCC.command.line':
  [     0]  -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu
  [    1d]  test.c
  [    24]  -mtune=generic
  [    33]  -march=x86-64
  [    41]  -frecord-gcc-switches
  [    57]  -fno-stack-protector
```

When **GCC** is passed the `-frecord-gcc-switches` switch, it will add the `.GCC.comment.line` section -- containing the switches passed to **GCC** -- to the binary **ELF** file it creates.

You can then use `readelf` to print out the relevant section from your binary **ELF** file and search for the existence of the `-fno-stack-protector` switch to determine if the binary file has been compiled with stack-smashing on/off.

Unfortunately, this solution is limited to binary files compiled using the `-frecord-gcc-switches` -- which effectively means it's useless for the majority of situations, though perhaps you may luck out in your particular case.

---

It's worth mentioning that the detection of buffer overflow vulnerabilities in binary files is an active area of research. For instance, here's a [research paper detailing a simple detection module (see section 7.1)](http://www.kau.edu.sa/Files/0053027/Researches/29116_Buffer_Overflow_Vulnerability_Detection_in_Binary_Code_INFOS.pdf).

### See also

> [Get the compiler options from a compiled executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12112479/1806289)

Answer (score 3):

The `checksec` command can be used to check for stack protection measures (along with other binary security properties):

```
checksec --file /usr/bin/ls
RELRO           STACK CANARY      NX            PIE             RPATH      RUNPATH      Symbols     FORTIFY Fortified   Fortifiable FILE
Full RELRO      Canary found      NX enabled    PIE enabled     No RPATH   No RUNPATH   No Symbols  Yes     5           17          /usr/bin/ls
```

Note that `STACK CANARY` indicates whether stack protection is enabled for the executable.

This command can be installed via the package manager for most linux distributions; the bash script it uses can also be downloaded from its [github repo](https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh).