# Are there compiler options in clang

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc, c++11

I am learning from The C++ Primer. One of the exercises is to compile a program with arguments in `main()`. For this I am trying to use mac terminal.

I need to compile a C++11 Unix executable file named `main` which takes `f` as an argument. I am using Xcode 4.6.3 on OS X Lion.

I compiled the program with `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp -o main`.
But don’t know what to do next.

I found [-frecord-gcc-switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112338/get-the-compiler-options-from-a-compiled-executable) while searching compiler options on google. It does what I need to do. Is there a clang version of this?

Please use simple language. I have never used command line before. I tried going through the clang manual but a lot of it is out of my depth.

Comment: I am bumping this as I cant find this answer on google... Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. What is it you want the computer to *do*?

Comment: I want to give an argument to the main function that i wrote in C++. It takes f as an argument and prints “Hello World”.

Comment: OK, see my answer. I think, more generally than getting an argument to `main()`, you just want to run the darn thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler didn't complain about anything, you should have a fresh new file named `main` in the same directory as the source file, and you can run it from the command line using `./main -f` or the like.

Comment: Thank you! It works! Are there any books on this that I can read?

Comment: @Deohboeh I suppose you just want any introduction to the UNIX command line… but that's considered "not programming" and off topic for this site. You also might consider using XCode which provides a graphical interface including a terminal window that runs your program automatically.