# How can I see which compilation options are enabled on Intel ICC compiler?

Tags: c++, g++, icc

Is there an equivalent of the following g++ command on icc/icpc intel compiler ?

```
?> g++ -march=native -m32 ... -Q --help=target
```

Which gave me the following output:

```
The following options are target specific:
  -m128bit-long-double                  [disabled]
  -m16                                  [disabled]
  -m32                                  [enabled]
  -m3dnow                               [disabled]
  -m3dnowa                              [disabled]
  -m64                                  [enabled]
  -m80387                               [enabled]
  -m8bit-idiv                           [disabled]
  -m96bit-long-double                   [enabled]
  -mabi=                                sysv
  -mabm                                 [disabled]
  -maccumulate-outgoing-args            [disabled]
  -maddress-mode=                       short
  -madx                                 [disabled]
  -maes                                 [disabled]
  -malign-data=                         compat
  -malign-double                        [disabled]
  -malign-functions=                    0
  -malign-jumps=                        0
  -malign-loops=                        0
  -malign-stringops                     [enabled]
  -mandroid                             [disabled]
  -march=                               nehalem
  -masm=                                att
  -mavx                                 [disabled]
  -mavx2                                [disabled]
  -mavx256-split-unaligned-load         [disabled]
  -mavx256-split-unaligned-store        [disabled]
  -mavx512bw                            [disabled]
  -mavx512cd                            [disabled]
  -mavx512dq                            [disabled]
  -mavx512er                            [disabled]
  -mavx512f                             [disabled]
  -mavx512ifma                          [disabled]
  -mavx512pf                            [disabled]
  -mavx512vbmi                          [disabled]
  -mavx512vl                            [disabled]
  -mbionic                              [disabled]
  -mbmi                                 [disabled]
  -mbmi2                                [disabled]
  -mbranch-cost=                        0
  -mcld                                 [disabled]
  -mclflushopt                          [disabled]
  -mclwb                                [disabled]
  -mcmodel=                             32
  -mcpu=                      
  -mcrc32                               [disabled]
  -mcx16                                [enabled]
  -mdispatch-scheduler                  [disabled]
  -mdump-tune-features                  [disabled]
  -mf16c                                [disabled]
  -mfancy-math-387                      [enabled]
  -mfentry                              [enabled]
  -mfma                                 [disabled]
  -mfma4                                [disabled]
  -mforce-drap                          [disabled]
  -mfp-ret-in-387                       [enabled]
  -mfpmath=                             387
  -mfsgsbase                            [disabled]
  -mfused-madd                
  -mfxsr                                [enabled]
  -mglibc                               [enabled]
  -mhard-float                          [enabled]
  -mhle                                 [disabled]
  -mieee-fp                             [enabled]
  -mincoming-stack-boundary=            0
  -minline-all-stringops                [disabled]
  -minline-stringops-dynamically        [disabled]
  -mintel-syntax              
  -mlarge-data-threshold=               0x10000
  -mlong-double-128                     [disabled]
  -mlong-double-64                      [disabled]
  -mlong-double-80                      [enabled]
  -mlwp                                 [disabled]
  -mlzcnt                               [disabled]
  -mmemcpy-strategy=          
  -mmemset-strategy=          
  -mmmx                                 [enabled]
  -mmovbe                               [disabled]
  -mmpx                                 [disabled]
  -mms-bitfields                        [disabled]
  -mmwaitx                              [disabled]
  -mno-align-stringops                  [disabled]
  -mno-default                          [disabled]
  -mno-fancy-math-387                   [disabled]
  -mno-push-args                        [disabled]
  -mno-red-zone                         [disabled]
  -mno-sse4                             [disabled]
  -mnop-mcount                          [disabled]
  -momit-leaf-frame-pointer             [disabled]
  -mpc32                                [disabled]
  -mpc64                                [disabled]
  -mpc80                                [disabled]
  -mpclmul                              [disabled]
  -mpcommit                             [disabled]
  -mpopcnt                              [enabled]
  -mprefer-avx128                       [disabled]
  -mpreferred-stack-boundary=           0
  -mprefetchwt1                         [disabled]
  -mprfchw                              [disabled]
  -mpush-args                           [enabled]
  -mrdrnd                               [disabled]
  -mrdseed                              [disabled]
  -mrecip                               [disabled]
  -mrecip=                    
  -mrecord-mcount                       [disabled]
  -mred-zone                            [enabled]
  -mregparm=                            0
  -mrtd                                 [disabled]
  -mrtm                                 [disabled]
  -msahf                                [enabled]
  -msha                                 [disabled]
  -mskip-rax-setup                      [disabled]
  -msoft-float                          [disabled]
  -msse                                 [enabled]
  -msse2                                [enabled]
  -msse2avx                             [disabled]
  -msse3                                [enabled]
  -msse4                                [enabled]
  -msse4.1                              [enabled]
  -msse4.2                              [enabled]
  -msse4a                               [disabled]
  -msse5                      
  -msseregparm                          [disabled]
  -mssse3                               [enabled]
  -mstack-arg-probe                     [disabled]
  -mstack-protector-guard=              tls
  -mstackrealign                        [enabled]
  -mstringop-strategy=                  [default]
  -mtbm                                 [disabled]
  -mtls-dialect=                        gnu
  -mtls-direct-seg-refs                 [enabled]
  -mtune-ctrl=                
  -mtune=                               nehalem
  -muclibc                              [disabled]
  -mveclibabi=                          [default]
  -mvect8-ret-in-mem                    [disabled]
  -mvzeroupper                          [disabled]
  -mx32                                 [disabled]
  -mxop                                 [disabled]
  -mxsave                               [disabled]
  -mxsavec                              [disabled]
  -mxsaveopt                            [disabled]
  -mxsaves                              [disabled]

  Known assembler dialects (for use with the -masm-dialect= option):
    att intel

  Known ABIs (for use with the -mabi= option):
    ms sysv

  Known code models (for use with the -mcmodel= option):
    32 kernel large medium small

  Valid arguments to -mfpmath=:
    387 387+sse 387,sse both sse sse+387 sse,387

  Known data alignment choices (for use with the -malign-data= option):
    abi cacheline compat

  Known vectorization library ABIs (for use with the -mveclibabi= option):
    acml svml

  Known address mode (for use with the -maddress-mode= option):
    long short

  Known stack protector guard (for use with the -mstack-protector-guard= option):
    global tls

  Valid arguments to -mstringop-strategy=:
    byte_loop libcall loop rep_4byte rep_8byte rep_byte unrolled_loop vector_loop

  Known TLS dialects (for use with the -mtls-dialect= option):
    gnu gnu2
```

This gcc/g++ option give me a lot of usefull information like:
 `m32` and `msse4.2` is `enabled`,
`march` is `nehalem`,
`mfpmath` is `387`,
`masm` is `att`, ect...

I am really interested to know if an option like that exist for Intel icc/icpc compiler.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if the question included the actual output from g++ for the options shown.

Comment: I added it, thanks for the advice (+1).

Comment: I prefer to use the GCC option `-v`: `$ gcc -v test.c` will print something like: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/cc1 -quiet -v a.c -march=sandybridge -mmmx -mno-3dnow -msse ...`. Maybe it will work also in icc?

Comment: Check `-help[category]` option described on page *405* of [Intel(R) C++ Compiler User and Reference Guides](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~bnikolic/QTTG/shared/docs/intel_c_user_and_reference_guide.pdf). I don't have *icpc* compiler, but you can check if it prints only parameters description.

Comment: I've found interesting `icpc` flag called `-sox` (page [983 of the manual](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~bnikolic/QTTG/shared/docs/intel_c_user_and_reference_guide.pdf)). Quote: *This option tells the compiler to save the compiler options and version number in
the executable.  (...) It is then possible to use a tool, such as a strings
utility, to determine what options were used to build the executable file.* BTW: `gcc` has [similar option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112338/get-the-compiler-options-from-a-compiled-executable).

Comment: Unfortunately, the `icc -sox` flag does not save the optimization flags enabled by `-march=native`.  `gcc -frecord-gcc-switches` seems to embed all the enabled flags.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follows:

```
icpc    -dM -E -x c++ *.c
```

The former combined with the options:

```
-vec-report[=n]
           control amount of vectorizer diagnostic information
             n=0    no diagnostic information
             n=1    indicate vectorized loops (DEFAULT when enabled)
             n=2    indicate vectorized/non-vectorized loops
             n=3    indicate vectorized/non-vectorized loops and prohibiting
                    data dependence information
             n=4    indicate non-vectorized loops
             n=5    indicate non-vectorized loops and prohibiting data
                    dependence information
             n=6    indicate vectorized/non-vectorized loops with greater
                    details and prohibiting data dependence information
             n=7    indicate vector code quality message ids and data values
                    for vectorized loops

 -qopt-report[=n]
           generate an optimization report. Default destination is
           <target>.optrpt.  Levels of 0 - 5 are valid.
           Please see documentation for additional details of
           information provided by phase per level.
             0   disable optimization report output
             2   DEFAULT when enabled

 -qopt-report-file=[stdout | stderr | <file>]
           specify the filename or output stream for the generated report

 -qopt-report-stdout
           specify the generated report should be directed to stdout

 -qopt-report-per-object
           specify the generated report should be directed to a .optrpt file
           in the output directory (DEFAULT when another destination for the
    report is not specified)

 -qopt-report-phase=<phase>[,<phase>,...]
           specify one or more phases that reports are generated against

 -qopt-report-routine=<name>[,<name>,...]
           restrict the report to routines containing the given name

 -qopt-report-filter=<string>
           restricts the opt-report to specific files, routines or line
           number ranges. Refer to the documentation for the specific
           syntax of parameter string.

 -qopt-report-format=[text|vs]
           specify the output format to be used for the opt-report as either
           plain text or a format for use in the Microsoft* Visual Studio IDE

 -q[no-]opt-report-embed
           When enabled, if an assembly file is being generated, special loop
           info annotations will be emitted in the assembly file.  If an object
           file/executable is being generated, these will be emitted into the
           object file/executable for use by the Intel VTune Amplifier
           application. Automatically enabled when symbolic debug information
           is enabled.

 -qopt-report-help
           display the optimization phases available for reporting

 -qopt-report-names=<keyword>
           Specifies whether mangled or unmangled names should appear in the
           optimization report.
             mangled   - use mangled names
             unmangled - use unmangled names (DEFAULT)

 -tcheck [mode]
           enable analysis of threaded applications (requires Intel(R) Thread
           Checker; cannot be used with compiler alone)
             tci - instruments a program to perform a thread-count-independent
                   analysis
    tcd - instruments a program to perform a thread-count-dependent
                   analysis (DEFAULT when mode is not used)
             api - instruments a program at the api-imports level

 -tcollect[=<lib>]
           inserts instrumentation probes calling the Intel(R) Trace Collector
           API.  The library -l<lib> is linked in the default being -lVT
           (requires Intel(R) Trace Collector)

 -tcollect-filter file
           Enable or disable the instrumentation of specified functions. 
           (requires Intel(R) Trace Collector)
```

will provide you enought information. I hope that this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Intel Compiler supports -help compiler option and provides an option to filter the output based on categories as shown below:

```
icpc -help
.
.
-help [category]   print full or category help message

 Valid categories include
   advanced        - Advanced Optimizations
   codegen         - Code Generation
   compatibility   - Compatibility
   component       - Component Control
   data            - Data
   deprecated      - Deprecated Options
   diagnostics     - Compiler Diagnostics
   float           - Floating Point
   help            - Help
   inline          - Inlining
   ipo             - Interprocedural Optimization (IPO)
   language        - Language
   link            - Linking/Linker
   misc            - Miscellaneous
   opt             - Optimization
   output          - Output
   pgo             - Profile Guided Optimization (PGO)
   preproc         - Preprocessor
   reports         - Optimization Reports
   openmp          - OpenMP and Parallel Processing
```

For this specific request from you, you can get options in codegen category.

Comment: this provides only help, while `gcc -Q --help=target` shows selected options like -march=skylake