# Is there a way to store clang compile-time flags in the output binary?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

Is there a way to store the compile-time flags in the output binary when using clang?

For example after running:

`clang -O3 -c main.c`

The resulting `main.o` file should somewhere contain `-O3`.

[gcc has `-frecord-gcc-switches`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112338/get-the-compiler-options-from-a-compiled-executable) but I'm unable to find an equivalent for clang.

Comment: Note: Clang feature request: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16291

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ecatmur already has implied in the comments. This feature is currently not supported as documented in bug https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16291 .

However as a work around while the feature is not available I would suggest having your build process define a macro inside the program using clang's `-D` argument. For example assuming you are invoking this from a bash script (adjust to whatever build tool you use):

```
CLANG_ARGS='-O3 -c main.c'
clang $CLANG_ARGS -D CLANG_ARGS="\"${CLANG_ARGS}\""
```

Then in your C or C++ programs you add something along the lines of:

```
const char clangArgs[] = CLANG_ARGS;
```

Which you can then retrieve using a debugger or some such or even could add some code to print it from your program when invoked with the `-V` or `--version` switch.