# How can I determine if UBSAN has been compiled in using clang or gcc?

Tags: c++, clang, ubsan, address-sanitizer

We use the following code to determine if `-fsanitize=address` has been specified at compile time for clang and gcc. How do we determine if `-fsanitize=undefined` has been specified?

```
    bool isSanitized = false;
#if defined(__has_feature)
#if __has_feature(address_sanitizer)
    isSanitized = true;
#endif
#elif defined(__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__)
    isSanitized = true;
#endif
```

Comment: You might check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719560/is-there-a-way-to-store-clang-compile-time-flags-in-the-output-binary

Comment: That doesn't work the same way as ASAN detection.

Comment: A request for this was opened at https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/765 and subsequently closed for lack of a convincing use case.

Comment: The USE CASE is that UBSAN is sometimes BUGGY. And you have to write code to workaround it.

Comment: I almost flagged this as a dup, but that one is about gcc only: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34813412/1012586

Comment: The use case is that ubsan has different requirements to symbol visibility as it turns static casts in to dynamic ones that requires otherwise opaque classes to be exported

Answer (score 4):

With Clang, you can now check for UBSan very similarly to how you can check for ASan:

```
#if defined(__has_feature)
#  if __has_feature(undefined_behavior_sanitizer)
#    define HAS_UBSAN 1
#  endif
#endif
```

I don't know if it's possible to check under GCC yet though.

Comment: The solution for gcc can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34814667/1012586

Comment: Apparently it was rejected for GCC, because they didn't believe it would make sense. https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2019-09/msg01286.html

Considering ubsan builds are not binary compatible with non-ubsan build because it makes static casts into dynamic casts. I find this infuriating.

Answer (score 3):

A request for this was opened at https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/765 and subsequently closed for lack of a convincing use case.

A hack to detect presence of ubsan at run time is to look for one of its symbols, typically a symbol associated with the undefined behavior you are interested in. For example, to detect whether ubsan is sanitizing `__builtin_unreachable` you can check for the presence of `__ubsan_handle_builtin_unreachable`:

```
extern "C" void __attribute__((weak)) __ubsan_handle_builtin_unreachable();

if (&__ubsan_handle_builtin_unreachable)
    ; // ubsan is present
else
    ; // ubsan is not present
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you file this as a bug to ASan github (or GCC bugzilla) about this (we already have defined for ASan and TSan so it makes sense to cook one for UBSan as well). For now it seems your only option is to pass a custom define together with `-fsanitize-undefined` in a Makefile.