# Is there a method to make `gcc' dump/display all the flags in use while compiling code?

Tags: gcc, arm

Do note this is different from
[Get the compiler options from a compiled executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112338/get-the-compiler-options-from-a-compiled-executable) which I did go through in detail.

Although `-frecord-gcc-switches` is great, it only captures the command line arguments.

For example, I am not interested in capturing `-O2` which is usually passed in command line. I am more curious about recording all the flags like `-fauto-inc-dec` which are enabled by `-O2`.

(In contrast to the link above, do note that I have access to the source, the compiler and the build infrastructure. I just want to capture the flags during compilation. Not picky about any specific gcc version)

Comment: Used to be -frecord-options-in-elf

Comment: Thanks @Severin. '-frecord-options-in-elf` unfortunately doesn't seem to be working (as of gcc v5.2.1).
I do see some dev work, but, I'm unable to trace it [link](http://gcc-patches.gcc.gnu.narkive.com/Q5LBr1SX/google-record-compiler-options-to-note-sections)

Comment: Yeah, I remember some discussion why it should be in/shouldn't be in, at some point it was there and then it wasn't... You have to dig around, I guess

Comment: And, frankly, it is only possible/useful to get options from single compilation unit (aka .o file). Noone guarantee files in executable are compiled with the same options, and for all projects I worked on with external libraries, our libraries, system libraries, I'm pretty sure they were all compiled a bit differently - and ABI takes care of the rest

Comment: Yep, I'm interested only in flags on a per compilation unit basis
(Of course there would be a ton of differences between different CUs, not looking for any global flag !)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `-fverbose-asm`. That dumps the optimisation options used in a comment at the top of the assembly file.