# identify whether an ELF binary is built with optimizations

Tags: gcc, optimization, elf

I know we can use cmake or make to control `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` for building release version manually. `release` version to me means `-O2` or `-O3` is given at least,  it doesn't matter whether `-g` or `strip` is performed,  whereas `debug` is given `-O0`.

However sometimes I want use scripts to decide whether an elf binary was built with optimizations, so I can decide what to do next. I tried `objdump` or `file` or `readelf`, but found no answers. Are there any alternatives that I can do this ?

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9638449 It's hard according to this paper. No off-the-shelf method at present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However sometimes I want use scripts to decide whether an elf binary was built with optimizations, so I can decide what to do next.

The problem with your question is that your binary is very likely to contain *some* code built with optimizations (e.g. `crt0.o` -- part of GLIBC).

Your final binary is composed of a bunch of object files, and these files *do not* have to have consistent optimization flags.

Most likely you only care about the code you wrote (as opposed to code linked from other libraries). You could use `-frecord-gcc-switches` for that. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12112479/50617).