# How to print the GCC optimization options?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'm trying to compile my test program with various [GCC optimizations options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and I'd like to see all of them in the program output. Something like that (the `__cpp_optimizations` constant is invented for this question):

```
std::cout << __cpp_optimizations << std::endl;
```

Is it any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

[Get the compiler options from a compiled executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112338/get-the-compiler-options-from-a-compiled-executable) . Compile with `-frecord-gcc-switches` than read the command line options from the executable, in pseudocode:

```
buf = popen(std::string() + "readelf -p .GCC.command.line /proc/self/exe").read()
// or read elf yourself instead of popen
// tokenize buf, get all compiler options
// filter out only optimization options
```

Alternatively, you could instruct your *build system* to pass that information as a macro. For example, in CMake:

```
add_compile_options(-O3)
add_compile_definitions("CPP_OPTIMIZATIONS=\"-O3\"")
```